# About Except+adv

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositions, difference

> He has in no way changed except eternally.

a)He changed.

b)He didn’t change.

Which one is correct?

> He always goes hiking except recently.

I know these two examples are different but I wonder what the difference is.

Answer (score 1):

I think the first one would be externally and not eternally. Which I presume might mean, he's dead. Dead for eternity. Externally would be, Oh he just puts on an act of having changed for good, but internally he's still the same devil that he is. So I say, He hasn't changed. (His habits, his clothes, his shoes, etc.) He always went hiking, that is until recently.